# RecyclerView скроллится к верхней границе элемента при его касании

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-view

Есть `RecyclerView` с некоторым количеством элементов. Каждый элемент, по большому счету, состоит из контейнера и `TextView`. Проблема заключается в том, что `RecyclerView` при касании элемента автоматически прокручивается до верхней границы, если она не видна.

Это происходит только один раз после очередной отрисовки элемента, т.е. такая реакция наблюдается только при первом касании между вызовами `onBindViewHolder()` и `onViewRecycled()`.

Что может приводить к такому поведению и как этого избежать?

[Пример](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7PB7XApvO8VaEgxaDR4RVVmMUU)

Comment: Возможно фокусирует на выбранное `view`, я решал подобные проблемы отключением фокуса у ресайкла. `recyclerView.setFocusable(false);`, так же можете поиграться с отключением фокусировки у других вложенных в ресайкл `view` элементов

Comment: @McDaggen, спасибо, ``recyclerView.setFocusable(false)`` ничего не меняет, ``textView.setFocusable(false)`` работает, но теряется возможность выделения текста по длинному нажатию, так что вариант так себе..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)